# Does FFMpeg's "avoid_negative_ts" always cause desync?

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp, synchronization

FFMpeg has an optional command line argument `avoid_negative_ts` with values either `make_zero` or `make_non_negative`, does this option just always desynchronize audio and video tracks from how they were originally? If yes, then what's the point of it? And if not then how exactly does it work if it changes timestamps without affecting synchronization? Obviously talking about a situation when it does anything, not when timestamps were originally at 0 anyway.

Comment: It simply applies some offset to all output streams - it shouldn't change the original sync.

Comment: @Gyan It does seem to affect it, for example 1 clip I have cut out without reencoding as mp4 has with `avoid_negative_ts` turned on video stream start at `start_pts=3600` `start_time=0.040000` and audio stream at 0, when it's turned off, both streams start at 0, this also seems counterintuitive as the option changes it from 0 to 0.04 rather than bringing it to 0, this has happened in multiple files so I'm not sure how it works exactly.

Comment: @chasemhalasem Any luck on this? Also wondering this same question myself.